# Why my self-defined metrics in keras failed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a three-class classifier, which is implemented in keras. (0, 1, 2)
I want to get precision rate for every training, so i defined metric function like this:

```
def precision_pos(y_true, y_pred):
    # Calculates the precision
    true_positives = K.sum(K.cast(K.round(y_true * y_pred)==1, dtype='float32'))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.cast(K.round(y_pred)==1, dtype='float32'))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def precision_neg(y_true, y_pred):
    true_neg = K.sum(K.cast(K.round(y_true * y_pred)==4, dtype='float32'))
    predicted_neg = K.sum(K.cast(K.round(y_pred)==2, dtype='float32'))
    print(true_neg)
    print(predicted_neg)
    precision_neg = true_neg / (predicted_neg + K.epsilon())
    return precision_neg

def precision_neu(y_true, y_pred):
    true_neu = K.sum(K.cast(K.round(y_true * y_pred)==0, dtype='float32'))
    predicted_neu = K.sum(K.cast(K.round(y_pred)==0, dtype='float32'))
    print(true_neu)
    print(predicted_neu)
    precision_neu = true_neu / (predicted_neu + K.epsilon())
    return precision_neu
```

I think the first function worked well, but the other two not. please see the output:

```
512/512 [==============================] - 4s 8ms/sample - loss: 7.2359 - precision_pos: 0.4674 - precision_neg: 0.0000e+00 - precision_neu: 2.8859
Train on 512 samples
512/512 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/sample - loss: 8.7310 - precision_pos: 0.5264 - precision_neg: 0.0000e+00 - precision_neu: 80000008.0000
Train on 512 samples
512/512 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/sample - loss: 7.1996 - precision_pos: 0.2750 - precision_neg: 0.6720 - precision_neu: 600000000.0000
Train on 512 samples
512/512 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/sample - loss: 9.9930 - precision_pos: 0.1250 - precision_neg: 10625000.0000 - precision_neu: 640000000.0000
Train on 512 samples
512/512 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/sample - loss: 7.7442 - precision_pos: 0.0625 - precision_neg: 8750000.0000 - precision_neu: 640000000.0000
Train on 512 samples
512/512 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/sample - loss: 9.3498 - precision_pos: 0.0000e+00 - precision_neg: 10625000.0000 - precision_neu: 640000000.0000
Train on 512 samples
512/512 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/sample - loss: 9.4443 - precision_pos: 0.0000e+00 - precision_neg: 5625000.0000 - precision_neu: 640000000.0000
```

Can anyone help on this? i think inner product == 4 is the class '2' predict well samples, pred==2 is all the predict 2 samples, so it wont be larger than 1, am i right?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating your **Custom Metrics**, you should investigate your **rounding off's** and **multiplications**.

Specifically these lines,

```
def precision_neg(y_true, y_pred):
    true_neg = K.sum(K.cast(K.round(y_true * y_pred)==4, dtype='float32'))
    ## Rest of the code

def precision_neu(y_true, y_pred):
    true_neu = K.sum(K.cast(K.round(y_true * y_pred)==0, dtype='float32'))
    ## Rest of the code
```

Focusing on your base operation `K.round(y_true * y_pred)`, this returns values that when rounded off is equal to `3`, ie. `2.7405417`. Therefore, you get data that is unhandled properly,  that's why you get precision metrics greater than `1`.
You could try to work around this by applying `if-else` methods and/or using `tf.math.ceil` or `tf.math.floor`, or even explicitly indicating that when the value is equal to `3` replace with a certain value.